# abbreviation and def.article

Tags: abbreviations

Hi what is better to use?

Traditonal Library of WrUT ( WrUT is a Wroclaw University of Wroclaw)

or Traditonal Library of **the** WrUT

2.Visit the website of WrUT Libraries’
or Visit the website of the WrUT Libraries’
thanks Jola

Answer (score 2):

Since the university is autonomous, it's better to use the latter. Also, it does sound better than the first one.